# python array slice, what happens here?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm stuck on a problem regarding python array slicing.

I have 2 `numpy.ndarrays`:

`img` is a 1d array (256 length)

`optimised` is an 2d array (231x50)

what happens here? how is result made up?

```
result = img[optimised.astype('uint8')]  # result is a 2d 231x50 array
```

Is there a equivalent in javascript?

Comment: Are those [`array`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), or panda dataframes or similar…?

Comment: these are arrays

Comment: The builtin Python `array` class doesn't have a method `astype`…

Comment: you're right, they're both numpy.ndarray's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should clarify what happens. Each value from `a` used as index in `b` and put in the same place. So `a[0, 0]` is 1 and `b[1]` is 28 so in resulting array `[0, 0]` element will be 28.

```
>>> a
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
>>> b
array([13, 28])
>>> b[a]
array([[28, 13],
       [13, 28]])
```